# How to replace the string in the file through command line in the most simple way?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, command-line

Suppose the file 'file', in which there is the string

```
  c:\home users\XXX\
```

How to replace this string into

```
  d:\street users\YYY\ ?
```

P.S. The question holds after my failure with fart, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552198/cant-replace-text-with-spaces-with-fart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p "d:\street users\YYY\"<nul >test.txt
dir /b  c:\home users\XXX\file >>test.txt
```

Explanation:
First line creates a file that does not end with a new line. Second line appends a "BARE" listing of file. Hence:

```
type test.txt
```

should give you

```
d:\street users\YYY\file
```

If you want to execute a command then instead of a text file create a batch file.